# Count specific duplicates in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe

```
     loc        status
0    acs_blg    Check
1    qet_blg    Online
2    cna_blg    Offline
3    ppp_blg    Check
4    lck_blg    Online
```

I need to count the duplicate in status. I have tried:

```
df.groupby('status').status.count()
```

But this returns

```
status
Check    2
Offline  1
Online   2
```

How can I change my groupby code to just count duplicate of **only** "check" keyword?

end result

```
2
```

Comment: `df['status'].value_counts().max`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
len(df.loc[df['status'] == 'Check'].index)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried but this do not return a value. It is returning some kind of <bound method DataFrame.count .....>